# Postgres Double Precision to Date

Tags: postgresql, date, casting, precision

I'm looking to cast/convert a decimal data into date data. I've looked online and am still struggling. Can you help? "value" is a double precision, and here I convert it to varchar. From that point on, I've tried using convert but I'm still unable to get a date value.

Thanks in advance!

select cast(value as varchar(8) )date_value, value,

For example: The value 43099 should read 12/30/2017.

[image: Sample varchar(8) | value]

Comment: Please specify what the meaning of a `double precision` value is when interpreted as a `date`. Seconds since 1970-01-01, truncated to midnight?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I added a screenshot. Example: Our database stores the dates as values: 43099 (Should show 12/30/2017)

Comment: An example is good, but please define the semantics of these numbers.

Comment: Maybe:number of days since 1900-xx-yy?

Comment: @wildplasser: Almost my guess as well.

Comment: dc to the rescue here ...

Answer (score 3):

Guessing from your meager example, you might want this:

```
SELECT date '1899-12-30' + 43099; -- returns date '2017-12-30'
```

You need to cast your `value` column to `integer` for this:

```
SELECT date '1899-12-30' + value::int;
```

Meaning, the number might represent the count of days since 1900 (with an off-by-2 error I can't explain).

Adding an `integer` to a `date` means adding the number of days.

If your `value` can have fractional digits, you can compute a timestamp in similar fashion:

```
SELECT timestamp '1899-12-30' + interval '1 day' * value;
```